# Kubernetes : How to use a single Nginx server for all my applications?

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes

I have two services, an Nginx service(and deployment) in the `port 80` which is link to an ingress Nginx controller, and a WordPress service(deployment), which has a Nginx server in the `port 5050`.

So I have two services with two different Nginx servers, and I need to create a third service with `phpmyadmin` in it, and I will have to create an another Nginx server in a different port, `port 5000`.

That is why ask myself, if I can have a single Nginx service which is linked with all my applications(phpmyadmin, wordpress, …).

I have searched the web, and I found the terms frontend and backend tiers, but I don’t know how to use them, or if there is a different solution.
If someone can explain it to me in simple terms.

All my docker containers are self built.

Edit : ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  namespace: default
  name: ingress-controller
spec:
    backend:
      serviceName: my-nginx
      servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Are you using or considered to use `Ingress` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)? Your cluster is on local env or Cloud?

Comment: i use a nginx ingress controller which is connect to my nginx service, my cluster is on local env.

Comment: Could you share your configuration YAMLs?

Comment: Done, so ingress could connect to my wordpress  container even if there is not nginx in it ?

Comment: Ingress can redirect traffic to specific service. As you are using rewrite like https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ you can use it to redirect traffic (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061508/11148139) you would need to specify `host` and `path`. If you would curl test/wordpress you would get response from wordpress, if you would curl test/myphpadmin you would be redirected to myphpadmin. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, i want to have access to my services with just one server Nginx, because otherwise i will have three separate Nginx server for each services, that i install manually on each containers(Wordpress, Phpmyadmin, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned before in comments you have to use [Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) to redirect requests. I assume your services and deployments are connected properly. As additional info, if you would have some issues with current ingress I advise to use helm to deploy [Nginx](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress).

`Ingress` is also well documented on [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

You need to specify `paths` like in example below. All necessary information about `rewrite` can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /wordpress
        backend:
          serviceName: wordpress-service
          servicePort: <your service port>
      - path: /myphpadmin
        backend:
          serviceName: myphpadmin-service
          servicePort: <your service port>
      - path: /anotherservice
        backend:
          serviceName: another-service
          servicePort: <another service port>
```

Now if you will for example `$ curl test.local/wordpress` you will get response from `wordpress` service. I explained smimilar thing regarding `Ingress` in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061508/11148139).

As additional information, please keep in mind that there are more `Ingress` types (Nginx Ingress, GKE Ingress (if you are using GKE cloud), etc)

Comment: i will try that thanks

Comment: @bsteve were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: for now, no, but i have some problems with my deployments, i will retry later.